# How can I increase the volume in my headphones past what is put out from my laptop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, audio, headphones, hp-pavilion

I have a HP Pavilion DV6 and I need more volume than what my laptop's integrated/default sound card and software offer. Will an external USB soundcard resolve this and/or do I need to upgrade the software. Volume for integrated speakers is acceptable, but I need more volume on my headphones (which are a decent pair).

Comment: you could consider buying an amp for your headphones

Comment: You can get an external headphone amp pretty cheap - I have got a fiio e3 (which bumps up volume, and adds some bass), though a fiio e5 is a better choice.  Both would be dirt cheap and should make a difference

Answer (score 1):

An external USB soundcard can provide more volume than the internal one in a laptop. See this review of a [Asus Xonar U3 USB audio device](http://techreport.com/review/21256/asus-xonar-u3-usb-audio-device) at tech report as an example of one such product.

> With a native USB interface, the UA100 doesn't need a bridge chip to
>   interface with a host system. Asus has, however, incorporated the same
>   Texas Instruments DRV601RTJR headphone amplifier used in the Xonar DG.
>   The headphone amp makes a lot of sense given the U3's notebook
>   aspirations

Answer (score 0):

There are a few choices.

You say you have a decent pair of headphones, which suggest the impedance might be higher than standard heaphones (Sennheiser, Audio-Technica, Grado all often have higher Ohms, and need an amp (as already suggested), a sound card that can push more out, or a dedicated DAC.

I would go for the DAC, [and let your budget decide from there:](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=usb%20dac&rh=i:aps,k:usb%20dac)

A DAC generally will amplify more than a laptops onboard sound card.